# The use of different character types in C++

Tags: c++, char

The `wchar_t` type is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any character in the machine's largest extended character set. Why then have a need for `signed char` and `unsigned char` ? Furthermore, if there is indeed a reason to use the latter two in practice, can someone please provide small examples of when one would use `signed char` vs `unsigned char` ? The reason I ask the last question is because `char` is `signed` on some machines and `unsigned` on others. There is no default qualifier for `char`. C++ primer states that when using `char` you should make it explicit on which version you are using. I wonder why we even have a `signed char` if characters in the machine's basic character set are represented by the integrals 0 - 255.

Comment: `signed char` is for when you want negative to positive range of small numbers. There is some history behind the choice in keyword name if you want read about Dennis Ritchie but considering `char` simply as 1 byte of data is usually better than thinking of it as a character.

Comment: I use `unsigned char` for byte buffers, `char` for ASCII/UTF-8 (and when libraries make me), and I never use `signed char`.

Comment: The wchar_t type is _NOT_ guaranteed to be large enough to hold any character in the machine's largest extended character set.  The machine's basic character set are _usually but not always_ represented by the integrals 0 - 255.  They may also be 0 - 127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "`wchar_t` [is] large enough to hold any character in the machine's largest extended character set", we may know we're not storing anything "extended" and not wish to waste memory and slow the processing of text by using a larger type than we need.

`signed char` and `unsigned char` serve as storage for integral values in the range -128..127 and 0..255 respectively, so you use them when you want such a number and care about memory usage - or better yet use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` or similar, which have the advantage and disadvantage of implying the types are a correspondingly shorter form of the `[u]int16/32/64_t` types: that's clearer conceptually if you're storing a number, but as `int8_t` et al are just typedefs you may find your numbers making unwanted matches with overloads for `char` - for example, `my_int_8 = 65; std::cout << my_int_8` might print `'A'` (as the ASCII code 65 designates `'A'` rather than 65).

`unsigned char` also has special significance as the type able to read raw bits from memory in unions with arbitrary other types, per the Standard.

> C++ primer states that when using char you should make it explicit on which version you are using.

Nonsense.  If you're storing simple ASCII text (with values 0 to 127), use `char` and let the implementation choose which one to use.  This also answers another of your questions...

> I wonder why we even have a signed char if characters in the machine's basic character set are represented by the integrals 0 - 255.

...the "basic character set" is ASCII values 0 to 127 only.  Specific systems/protocols/programs may or may not give some implementation-specified significance or graphical representation to other character values.

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons. First is space efficiency: `wchar_t`s take up more space than is needed for ASCII characters (two times on windows, four on linux), which doesn't matter much for single values but is more important for arrays. String encoding where each and every character is as large as the largest Unicode value is called UTF-32, which incidentally isn't widely used because of this issue. See the Wikipedia article on UTF-8 for a smarter encoding.

The second is that `char` is a lot of times used as shorthand for byte-addressable memory. In this case you really should specify its signedness, or use `(u)int8_t` or somesuch, if you aren't just copying them straight.

As for why `signed`/`unsigned` isn't specified in the standard, that's mostly a compatibility issue. Specifying it either way would break someone's old code, and we can't have that, even if it would make things better in the long run. ASCII can fit in 0-127 anyways, which is probably why this hasn't been more of an issue.

Note that you shouldn't use `char` to store actual user-visible characters, lest you make non-western users very unhappy. `wchar_t` actually isn't correct either, at least on windows; it's big enough for most Unicode, but not all of it.

Answer (score 3):

`char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 different types, you can verify that by writing 3 overloaded functions, it compiles.

```
void f(char c) {}
void f(signed char c) {}
void f(unsigned char c) {}
```

In practice this doesn't have an impact on anything as `char` and `signed char` are easily auto-converted by the compiler in 99.9% of the cases but `char` and `signed char` are still two different types. Here is an example where you have to take into account that `char` and `signed char` are different:

```
template <typename T> void f(T c) {}
void f(char c) {}
void f(unsigned char c) {}

typedef signed int MyIntType;

int test()
{
    MyIntType i = 5;
    // This f() call will call the template function not the char overload!
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I found this example in a serialization framework. In this case you have to handle all 3 `char` types with specific overloads if you want to avoid the "fallback" template method.

The original purpose of the `char` type was storing/processing text but most legacy codebases exploit the fact that mainstream compilers define their `char` types as signed 8 bit integer (most opensource libraries would break if this wasn't true). When you work with data use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` or define your own `int8` and `uint8` types for each supported platform.

On windows `wchar_t` is 16 bit. This size was burnt into windows and VC++ when we thought that 16 bit would be enough to hold all unicode characters (old UCS times). Today there are about 1 million characters in the unicode table. Windows handles this by using utf-16 encoding (instead of UCS) so some unicode characters are stored in two `wchar_t` instances (google "utf-16 surrogate pair").

On most unix systems `wchar_t` is 32 bit. If you are writing a text encoding library or something similar then you are better off using types with well defined sign and size (`uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the C and C++ language standards, the type `char` is the smallest addressable unit of memory on the platform. (Note:  some compilers and platforms may have extensions around this.)

So, to address a small unit of memory as a signed integer, the `signed char` type is often used.  You may also see `int8_t` used as well.  To access the memory as an unsigned integer, the `unsigned char` type is often used.

Also be aware that the definition of `char`, either signed, unsigned or plain, is compiler dependent.